# UITextField wont dismiss

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextfield

I am currently making an app that includes UITextFields and they have been working as intended but when I went to test my app recently I noticed that the keyboard does not dismiss after I have pressed on a UITextField. Before it acted like normal dismissing when I clicked away or pressed return but now I can not do anything to make it dismiss?

Here is my current ViewController code:

```
import UIKit

class CreateNewBudgetVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var grossIncomeVal: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var locationVal: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var federalExptVal: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var stateExptVal: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var deductionsList: UITableView!

    @IBAction func cancelPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "CancelSegue", sender: self)
    }

    @IBAction func generateBudgetPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let budget = Budget(grossIncome: Int(grossIncomeVal.text!)!)
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "GenerateSegue", sender: budget)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let budget = sender as? Budget, let destination = segue.destination as? BudgetVC {
            destination.budget = budget
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you implementing the `textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool` on UITextfieldDelegate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use

```
self.view.endEditing(true)
```

In the action methods defined above, where you want to dismiss the keyboard.

for eg

```
    @IBAction func cancelPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "CancelSegue", sender: self)
    }
```

and if you want to return keyboard in `return tap` of keyboard use this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate
```

and implement the delegate method

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {   //delegate method
   textField.resignFirstResponder()
   return true
}
```

but don't forget to assign `delegate to textfield`

```
yourTextField.delegate = self in `viewDidLoad`
```

and if you want to dismiss keyboard when tapped on outside just assign an tap gesture to your view like this

> In ViewDidload

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissKeyboard (_:)))
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

implement the dismiss function

```
func dismissKeyboard (_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: But the problem with this is it would only happen if I press that button right? The keyboard goes over the button so I need it to dismiss when I press away or press return

Comment: added one more way to dismiss keyboard when tapped outside view.